# How to get an actor reference (ActorRef) from ActorFlow?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

According to the [Play documentation on WebSockets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-Akka-Streams-and-actors) the standard way to establish a WebSocket is to use `ActorFlow.actorRef`, which takes a function returning the `Props` of my actor. My goal is to get a reference to this underlying `ActorRef`, for instance in order to send a first message or to pass the `ActorRef` to another actor's constructor.

In terms of the minimal example from the documentation, I'm trying to achieve this:

```scala
class WebSocketController @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) {

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    val flow = ActorFlow.actorRef { out => MyWebSocketActor.props(out) }
    // How to get the ActorRef that is created by MyWebSocketActor.props(out)?
    // Fictitious syntax (does not work)
    flow.underlyingActor ! "first message send"
    flow
  }
}
```

How can I get a reference to the actor that is created?

If it is not possible to get an `ActorRef` at this point (does it require materialization of the flow?), what would be the easiest way to store a reference to the created actor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Actor.preStart()` hook you can do some tricks to access the `actorRef`:

```
class MyWebSocketActor(
  out: ActorRef, 
  firstMessage: Any, 
  actorRegistry: ActorRef
) extends Actor {
  import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! firstMessage
    actorRegistry ! self
  }
  ...
}

def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
  ActorFlow.actorRef { out => 
    Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out, "First Message", someRegistryActorRef)) 
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I can avoid the `actorRegistry` approach. I have implemented a solution going in this direction in my actual use case, but the resulting code is fairly complex and it feels like I have to scatter a very simple logic into many unwanted pieces.

Comment: @bluenote10 I would argue, that getting the underlying actorRef breaks encapsulation, because its lifecycle is managed by the flow, and you can end up with a ref to a dead actor, because that actor's name is not unique, thus you can't count on its mailbox being delivered after respawn.

Comment: @bluenote10 I don't really know the _right_ way, but there is nothing stopping you from reimplementing `ActorFlow.actorOf`. The source code is open :)

Comment: I tried but I don't think it is possible, because the reference to the output actor is only available later.

Comment: @bluenote10 It is possible, here is a quick prototype https://gist.github.com/tsabirgaliev/4168639e991bd13e364c54def5c6d2cd