# How to send message to actor via web socket in Play! framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka, actor

This is rather a basic question but I couldn't find a satisfying answer after googling for hours. From the example in [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets), the way to make web socket is something like this:

Controller code:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.streams.ActorFlow
import javax.inject.Inject
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.Materializer

class Application @Inject()(cc:ControllerComponents) (implicit system: ActorSystem, mat: Materializer) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
      MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
    }
  }
}
```

Actor code:

```
import akka.actor._

object MyWebSocketActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out))
}

class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      out ! ("I received your message: " + msg)
  }
}
```

But how exactly do I send message from controller to the actor via web socket? Let's say  in the controller code, I have an action code that handles when a button is pressed, it will send a block of string to the actor. How do I send this string to the actor above from the controller code?

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this? I'm stuck with the same problem too.

Comment: @Peter I couldn't solve it. In the end I just used flask with java script.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with some examples of websockets in Play. Essentially they use a `Flow` (`akka-streams`) to handle a websocket connection.

There is an **official Play Websocket example**: [Lightbend's Websocket example](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-websocket-example)

Based on that, I have several projects that use websockets, for example:

**[play-wsocket-scalajs](https://github.com/pme123/play-wsocket-scalajs)**

This is an example application showing how you can integrate a Play project with a Scala.js, Binding.scala project - using Web Sockets.

It is quite involved, so the easiest way is to check [HomeController](https://github.com/pme123/play-wsocket-scalajs/blob/master/server/app/controllers/HomeController.scala), [UserParentActor](https://github.com/pme123/play-wsocket-scalajs/blob/master/server/app/actors/UserParentActor.scala), [UserActor](https://github.com/pme123/play-wsocket-scalajs/blob/master/server/app/actors/UserActor.scala) and [AdapterActor](https://github.com/pme123/play-wsocket-scalajs/blob/master/server/app/actors/AdapterActor.scala) how they work together.

**[scala-adapters](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters/)**

Is a framework that is based on the example above - that also shows how to register websocket clients.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand what is already created, and what we need to add. The type of `socket`, is a [`WebSocket`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html).

This `WebSocket`, reveals a single `apply` method:

```
def apply(request: RequestHeader): Future[Either[Result, Flow[Message, Message, _]]]
```

Therefore, as long as you did not send a message, the flow has not yet been created. Now, once a message is sent we can create the flow, and send it a meesage:

```
def index = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  socket(request).map {
    case Left(result) =>
      Ok("Done: Left: " + result.body)
    case Right(value) =>
      Source.single(TextMessage(Json.stringify(request.body))).via(value).to(Sink.ignore).run()
      Ok("Done: Right: ")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [sample app](https://github.com/johanandren/chat-with-akka-http-websockets/blob/akka-2.6/src/main/scala/chat/Server.scala) and [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229455/akka-http-websocket-true-bi-directional-scenario) might be helpful. Here's some code clipped/summarized from the linked sample app:

```
Flow.futureFlow(futureUserActor.map { userActor =>
  val incomingMessages: Sink[Message, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Message]
      .map(...)
      .to(...)

  val outgoingMessages: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
    ActorSource
      .actorRef[User.OutgoingMessage](...)
      .mapMaterializedValue { outActor =>
        // give the user actor a way to send messages out
        userActor ! User.Connected(outActor)
        NotUsed
      }
      .map(...)

  // then combine both to a flow
  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(incomingMessages, outgoingMessages)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to approach this:

1. Customize play's `ActorFlow.actorRef` method to return the underlying actor. There was a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923671/how-to-get-an-actor-reference-actorref-from-actorflow) before, here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tsabirgaliev/4168639e991bd13e364c54def5c6d2cd). If you put the underlying actor into a (user, websocket) map, make sure to use a thread-safe implementation like the [TrieMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/concurrent/TrieMap.html).
2. What you're trying to do could be solved by creating an event bus & subscribing to it from within the actor. Then you could filter the events you're interested in & react accordingly. This solution is better, in that it actually scales - you can have more than one replica of your web app (the 1st approach wouldn't work in that case, because a replica that doesn't hold the reference to a user's WS actor could receive button clicked event). In pseudo code to illustrate the idea:

```scala
sealed trait AppEvent
final case class ButtonClicked(user: User.ID) extends AppEvent

// inside an action
system.eventStream.publish(ButtonClicked(request.identity.id))

// inside your actor
override def preStart =
  context.system.eventStream.subscribe(self, classOf[AppEvent])
```

Please note that the idea of event bus is abstract. What I've demonstrated above is the most basic approach using akka's [classic event bus](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/event-bus.html), which works locally. For this approach to scale, you would need an actual message queue behind the scenes.