# Akka HTTP - Websocket - true bi-directional scenario

Tags: websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Trying to create a true bi-directional websocket server using akka http & akka-stream

- Server will answer a request when the response in ready
- Server will answer a request with multiple responses when those are ready
- Server will push a notification without being asked anything

The official https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html#handling-messages is not really clear.

Creating the Route for the server

```
  public Route createRoute() {
    return path("subscription", () ->
            get(() ->
                concat(
                    handleWebSocketMessages(subscriptionFlow()))));
  }

  public Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> subscriptionFlow() {
```

I find that you need to return the Flow that would handle the in/out messages.
Thinking that there is no request/response for the messages but just a weak link I will need a separate Sink for the requests and a separate Source for sending responses although the Sink still needs to know about the Source so it can later know to whom does this answer is sent to.

I have only found examples of request/response or the Sink is completely ignored and maybe one older example https://markatta.com/codemonkey/posts/chat-with-akka-http-websockets-old/

I am thinking to use `Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled` and maybe a have an actor that is created for every websocket connection

I cannot get to work the idea of `Sink.actorRefWithBackpressure`, `Source.actorRefWithBackpressure`, `Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled` and creating the actor for every websocket connection.

On the **typed Actor** (currently 2.6.3) I cannot find a way to create the actor for every websocket connection just like in the old example

```
val userActor = system.actorOf(Props(new User(chatRoom)))
```

Is there an example on akka / akka-stream / akka-http projects, or somewhere that shows this feature ?

Comment: This question is a bit broad to be easily answered. However, __`Flow` is enough for all your needs__. A `Flow` can emit messages after asynchronously processing inputs. A `Flow` can emit messages even without receiving input.

Comment: Here's an updated branch of that old sample using the new Actor APIs from 2.6 and the latest Akka HTTP: https://github.com/johanandren/chat-with-akka-http-websockets/tree/akka-2.6 in case that helps

Comment: @johanandren is it safe to use the guardian actor context [here](https://github.com/johanandren/chat-with-akka-http-websockets/blob/akka-2.6/src/main/scala/chat/Server.scala#L36)  . My understanding is that the function will be called when a new connection is created (is newUser() called from multiple threads ? - if yes then... wouldn't that be a problem as context is not thread safe)

Comment: Good catch, it is indeed not safe and would have to be a message interaction of some kind with the actor, using the `SpawnProtocol` for example.

Comment: I have now pushed a fix using `SpawnProtocol`.

Comment: I think the chat-with-akka-http-wesockets project is a good answer for this :)